# Suggesting to freelance for a design agency before applying for a job

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, applications, freelancing

A few months ago I decided I was going to leave my job at the design agency I was working for. I applied for a few other design agencies at the time that I liked the look of (even though none appeared to be hiring at the time).

There was one in particular that I was keen to work for, and the creative director replied to say he was really impressed with my work, and that there may be a designer vacancy opening in the new year.

It's now March and I've not heard anything. Aswell as that, I left my job a few weeks ago and decided that I would freelance in the meantime — I kinda needed to, as I was getting nothing for my portfolio from my previous job (aswell as a lot of other frustrations), so freelancing at the very least will help me to build my portfolio in the meantime.

I'm considering getting in touch with this agency again and asking if they are likely to have a vacancy anytime soon, but I'm also tempted to suggest to them that I could work on a freelance basis in the meantime, should they have a need for it.

I feel like this could benefit both of us, to check we are a right fit for each other.

Or should I just wait until they are hiring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or should I just wait until they are hiring?

No, you need a revenue stream so be proactive. The worst they can say is no.